# Why does the Minecraft-texture have black/dark borders in Cycles?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, light, image

I've used a spot-lamp as the only light source (the fire doesn't spread any light). Also, the problem shouldn't occur in the textures because i already checked it in different angles. If i look at it at the front of this "stair" the black/dark border disappeared. What is exactly the problem and how can i fix this? I've exported this world using jMc2Obj.

The following pictures may be of importance:

[image: problem]

Material of the stairs:

[image: material of the stairs]

Textures of the stairs:

[image: textures of the stairs]

Spotlight:

[image: spot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by Smooth Shading, to solve that you have to give your stairs model **Edge-Split Modifier.**

[image]

Before the ES Modifier
[image]

After the ES Modifier
[image]