# Black artifacts only in final render

Tags: rendering, materials

I have a rather simple glass material on a wine glass model, it renders perfectly fine in preview, but in final render it gets these black artifacts around edges.

I've checked other threads and tried tweaking the near/far clip but it doesnt seem to affect the issue. I've also upped the light paths to full global illumination.

Example:
[image: Preview render to left, final render to right]

Material and render settings:
[image: Material to the left, render settings to the right]

What could be the cause of this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check out this Answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36538/15366

Comment: It could be to do with flipped normals or even simply smooth shading applied to a subsurface mesh?

Comment: Thank you, you solved it! :) Problem  was smooth shading to subsurf

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Minecraft-texture have black/dark borders in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36537/why-does-the-minecraft-texture-have-black-dark-borders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was smooth shading, as pointed out by Igor Tatarnikov and Hexbob6.  I needed to apply an edge-split modifier to the problematic geometry to fix the issue.

See [Why does the Minecraft-texture have black/dark borders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36537/why-does-the-minecraft-texture-have-black-dark-borders-in-cycles/36538#36538)

Answer (score 0):

Also try the setting in finalrender for number of refraction passes, A glass needs 4 at least. increase and check if improved.