# Final render different than preview, black artifacts appear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, artifacts

**Update: Added edge split modifier, now it works. I don't understand any of this.**

I'm going crazy over this. Tried rendering in 2.75 and 2.76b. Same result.

I have this piece of a sword that just looks completely different on the final render than on the preview. And all the "render" vs. "view" settings are completely identical. And there are no object that render but are hidden or vice-versa.

The material is a mix of anisotropic and glossy, in the top right you can see the rendered .png and at the bottom it's my 3D view in render view. Do you see the black artifacts? They just won't go. I tried messing around with the subsurf modifier or rotate the mesh, but some black crap always appears anyway.

[image: What the hell is going on]

Just have a look at this. How come is the final render so different from preview in this simple case below?! (just Fresnel->Emission)

[image]

I don't understand what's going on. I thought the final render ought to be the same as preview in general. Let me repeat: subsurf has 3 subdivisions for the "View" and also 3 for the "Render". That's not where the difference's coming from.

Please, help me!

Comment: Ok, but it tells me I have to wait 1 more day until I can accept my own answer. Guess that's because I don't have much reputation/karma here.

Comment: Thank you for the friendly tips. I would surely elaborate on the issue, if I could, but I already said everything I know. I don't understand this problem and why  the fix fixes it :/ Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Edge Split modifier, as suggested in a similar question [-->here<--](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36659/black-artifacts-only-in-final-render?rq=1). Now it works.